# Change default ARPACK options for eigenvalue calculation for igraph package

Tags: r, igraph

According to the [CRAN igraph docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html), the `arpack_defaults()` provides the default values. I should be able to supply a named list to override the defaults, but I am unable to get the syntax correct. It works for `spectrum()` but fails for `centr_eigen()`, `eigen_centrality()`, or `evcent()`

```r
library(igraph)

# Create and Print Graph
bb <- graph_from_literal(E-D-A-B, A-C)
print(bb)
#IGRAPH dc36067 UN-- 5 4 -- 
#+ attr: name (v/c)
#+ edges from dc36067 (vertex names):
#[1] E--D D--A A--B A--C

# Changing the ARPACK option by providing a named list works here
spectrum(bb, which = list(pos = "LA"))$options$which   #[1] "LA"
spectrum(bb, which = list(pos = "LM"))$options$which   #[1] "LM"

# Functions below are not using the provided "LM" & instead using default "LA"
centr_eigen(bb, options = list(which = "LM"))$options$which      #[1] "LA"
eigen_centrality(bb, options = list(which = "LM"))$options$which #[1] "LA"
evcent(bb, options = list(which = "LM"))$options$which           #[1] "LA"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARPACK options can control two things in the most general case:

1. What to compute
2. How to compute it

Of course, `eigen_centrality()` computes a very specific thing: the eigenvector centrality, defined as the components of the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue. There is no room to change *what* it computes, only *how* it computes it. Elements of the ARPACK options controlling what to compute are overwritten.

If you need general eigenvalue computations with the adjacency matrix, use `spectrum()`. Note that even in this case, the `which` element of the ARPACK options will be overwritten by what you provide in the `which` argument. If you need eigenvector centrality, use `eigen_centrality()`.

Comment: Thank You for a clean explanation. (As I understand) You are essentially saying that although the `options` has been provided to change some parameters, the `which` parameter is not one of them. When the doc says "A named list to override **some** ARPACK options." It truly means 'some' and not 'all'.  I will accept your answer within a day :)

Comment: @Shivam7898 It depends on whether overriding a particular option makes sense for a given function. I believe that for the `arpack()` function all options should be overridable, but for some other functions this does not make sense. For example, if a function uses a single eigenvector, then it will ignore the option controlling the number of eigenvalues which are computed.